# Interface Builder NSButton for finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder, finder

Using interface builder, I want an a button that when clicked shows you a finder window and you can select a folder (not a file). How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify just what it is you're asking? Do you *really* want to open and restrict a Finder window, or are you asking how to show an "open file" dialog in your app, and restrict that dialog's selection to folders?

Comment: Both. But if you can just tell me how to "open file" I probably will figure the latter out on my own, thanks.

Comment: That's still confusing... Do you want to open the file and read its contents into your own app? Or cause a file to be opened with another app? And what does restricting Finder selection to folders have to do with either one? Seriously, I've been writing Cocoa for ten years now, and I'd like to help, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I just want to get the path to a folder, thats all. I could get the user to type the path in a textfield, but its much better if the user could navigate and point out visually the folder....

Comment: Okay, but Finder is the file-management app that opens up when you click the smiley face icon on the left of the dock. A "Finder window" has nothing at all to do with opening a dialog box in your own app to select a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the user to select a directory, use [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here's [an example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppFileMgmt/Tasks/UsingAnOpenPanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000777) of using it. To restrict what it can select, use its `-setCanSelectFiles:` and `-setCanSelectDirectories:` methods to configure it before calling its `-runModalForDirectory:file:types:` method.

Also, to trigger this from a button, just use IB to connect the button to an action method that you write, and use the above code in that method. See Apple's developer site for [details](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingAction.html).

Comment: -runModalForDirectory:file:types: method is deprecated. Use "runModal" instead